# how to match value of 1st list with the indexes of 2nd list in python

Tags: python

I am trying to match the value of 1st list with the indexes of 2nd list and if value and indexes match then in the result it will produce matches of the index value.

```
A = [0,2,0,5,2,1,1] # value of list 1
B = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] # value of 2nd list
```

the result should be,

`res = ['A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B']`

Comment: It would be really nice of you if you edit your question to the original one. These will create confusions to the future users regarding your question and the provided answers ...

Comment: sorry, for this. I will change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the code below,

```
A = [0, 2, 0, 5, 2, 1, 1] # values of list 1
B = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] # values of list 2

res = [B[i] for i in A if i<len(B)]
res
```

Output

```
['A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B']
```

Comment: It would be really nice of you if you edit your question to the original one. These will create confusions to the future users...

Comment: Try this out ```res = [[B[i], j, k] for i,j,k in A if i < len(B)]```

Comment: someone already answered but now i need this one the result list display like [['A', 0, 1], ['B', 2, 3], ['C', 5, 4]...]. how i will display like A (0, 1) \n B (2, 3) \n C (5, 4)\n

Comment: ```for i,j,k in res:
    print(i, (j,k))```

Comment: Thanks dude, here is last one. dictionary of A contains key (1, 2, 3, 4) and list of result contain A (0, 1) \n B (2, 3) \n C (5, 4). how i will display 1 = A (0, 1) \n 2 = B (2, 3) \n 3 = C (5,4)

Comment: `dictionary = {1: ['A', 0, 1], 2: ['B', 2, 3], 3: ['C', 1, 2], 4: ['A', 2, 1]}`
```for key, value in dictionary.items():
    print("{} = {} ({},{})".format(key, *value))```
Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: yeah, its working but in B case only display first value, like if in B case then only display B (2) whenever B will appear

Comment: I didn't get it.

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [0,2,0,5,2,1,1] # value of list 1
B = ["A", "B", "C", "D"] # value of 2nd list

new_list = []
for val in A:
    if val < len(B) - 1:
        new_list.append(B[val])

print(new_list)
```

Results:

```
['A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [0,2,0,5,2,1,1] # value of list 1
B = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] 

size_minus_1 = len(B) - 1

result = []
for i in A:
    if i < size_minus_1:
        result.append(B[i])

print(result)
```

Comment: ```result = []
for i in A:
    print(i)
    i[0] = B[i[0]]
    result.append(i)```

Comment: the result list display like [['A', 0, 1], ['B', 2, 3], ['C', 5, 4]...]. how i will display like A (0, 1) \n B (2, 3) \n C (5, 4)\n ...